# Connecting to AxonServer node [****] failed: UNAVAILABLE: Network closed for unknown reason

Tags: spring-boot, axon

I am new to axon server. I use axon server as remote server in spring boot. not in the localhost. but when the spring boot application connect to the server it fails and show the fallowing error.

```
Connecting to AxonServer node [174.298.31.***:8024] failed: UNAVAILABLE: Network closed for unknown reason
Failed to get connection to AxonServer. Scheduling a reconnect in 2000ms
```

my property file like below,

```yaml
axon:
  axonserver:
    servers: 174.298.31.***:8024
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you didn't change the default port, `8024` is the default port for HTTP access to the server dashboard. but when you try to connect to the server using a client, it is not the communication port, the communication protocol is `8124`. please try putting 8124 port. `8024` only for the dashboard.

```
axon:
  axonserver:
    servers: 174.298.31.***:8124
```

Comment: got it. it was the error. thanks for your support.